# Can I insert a JPA entity directly using QueryDSL?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, querydsl

Is there a way in QueryDSL to insert a JPA entity without using the JPA provider directly?

My use case issue is the following.  I am using Hibernate with a join table mapping between two entities.

Ex:

```
public class Contract implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Version
    @Column(name = "version")
    private Integer version;

    private String number;
    private String volume;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "contract_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "attachment_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private List<Attachment> attachments;
}
```

My problem is that if I try to add attachments in 2 separate threads simultaneously, I will get optimistic lock exceptions (as expected).  So instead, I would like to try to add the attachment directly via an SQL insert command.

Is there anyway of inserting an `Attachment` entity via QueryDSL as an object?  I couldn't find any reference documentation that covers this use case.  Only an update query, which requires setting the individual fields.

Pseudo code:

```
JPAQuery.insert(QAttachment.attachment).into(QContract.attachment).where(QContract.contract.id.eq(<contractId>));
```

Is something like this feasible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's not covered by Querydsl and also INSERT clauses are also not covered by the JPA API, so you will need to do the insertion via the JPA EntityManager API.

Comment: I was afraid of that.  Thanks for the clarification.